# PrimeVue (v3.29.2) -- What is `ThroughOptions`?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, primevue

I'm trying out [PrimeVue](https://primevue.org/) for a Vue3 project. Generally speaking it is very straightforward. However there is one concept that I don't quite understand: `ThroughOptions`.

Inside the the [API section](https://primevue.org/card/#api.card.interfaces.CardPassThroughOptions) of components there are many references to  `ThroughOptions` that are defined as `Custom passthrough(pt) options.`

For example:
| Name | Type | Description |
| :--- | :--- | :--- |
| header | CardPassThroughOptionType | Uses to pass attributes to the header's DOM element. |
| title | CardPassThroughOptionType | Uses to pass attributes to the title's DOM element. |

Can you please help me understand what those options are and how they can be used ?

Thanks

Comment: There is an example provided. The Card component is divided in `root`, `header`, `body` ... so in case you want to add some style to header, you can add class name as attribute: `<Card :pt="{ header: { class: 'bg-red' } }">...</Card>`

Comment: Thank you @VasileRadeanu.  How does this differ from using the built-in classes (ex: `.p-card-title { background-color: red; }` ?

Comment: @Nootaku Global styles change global behaviour which may not be desirable

Answer (score 0):

This question has been answered by @VasileRadeanu in the comments.

Meanwhile the documentation of Primevue has also been updated and the wireframes are available making it much easier to understand.

Please note that creating custom classes for your `<template>` elements require the use of `deep(.className) { some css arguments }` to be accessed. The `root` can be accessed directly.